# How to allow other people to upload content to your site

Tags: javascript, web, content-management-system

Hi,

I want to make a website where I can allow people to directly upload content (and it must be visible for other visitors without me having to manually add it) but I don't know where to start.
Is it smart to use a CMS, if so which one or is there an obvious answer like its just one line of JS?
(I do want to note that i'm a beginner coder so it might be a dumb question for the more advanced people)

Comment: Is there one line.....No , far from it. There is a lot involved in what you are asking. Use a CMS. Do some research into how dynamic content web sites work

Comment: Thank you, I think I found what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest, and easiest way is to use an existing, dedicated system, like CMS. CMSes usually have critical functionalities already built-in. Such functionalities are, for example:

- validating file types vs theirs contents
- blocking uploading files that may contain server-side executable code
- blocking files containing Javascript (to protect against XSS attacks)